# What data is posted back to the Paypal 'return' url, and how do I send my own data to this url?

Tags: paypal

Implementing a standard Paypal "Buy Now" button. The docs [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HH00W2J) are unclear as to  what data is passed to the 'return' url.  The docs also do not mention how to send your own custom data through the form.

Can anyone supply the appropriate documentation for this?

Relevant Code:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="mYAT+aR+YhVyBrulWoYoMjzY00DQggAXUVGI12TA6zk="></div>
      <input id="cmd" name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick">
      <input id="currency_code" name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD">
      <input id="notify_url" name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:3000/en/paypal_ipns/cart_purchase_ipn">
      <input id="item_name" name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Cart id 5398">
      <input id="quantity" name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1">
      <input id="business" name="business" type="hidden" value="seller_1318259_biz@me.net">
      <input id="return" name="return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost:3000/en/checkout/process_paypal_return">
      <input id="amount" name="amount" type="hidden" value="1.99">
      <input id="rm" name="rm" type="hidden" value="2">
      <p>
        <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have the transaction information returned to your page using PDT (Payment Data Transfer).  You can find more on it [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer).  You can also find a list of PDT variables that can get returned [here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables).  If you are wanting to pass over custom information, you can populate this into the variable "custom", and then parse that variable out once you are back on your return page.  I usually separate my different variables and values that I populate into the "custom" variable with a "|" but you can use whatever works for you.