# What data to process on 'return' URL in Paypal?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal payment system. For now, the user is being redirected to Paypal payment webpage after having clicked on the checkout button. When `Pay Now` button is triggered (I have been able to test the payment thanks to Test Credit Card Account Numbers found on Paypal website), it redirect the user to the URL I have set up in the sandbox. Everything work perfectly except when it comes to process data on the return page.

Here is the code of my form:

```
form = '<form id="paypalCheckout" style="display: none;" action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/acquiringweb" method="post">\
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">\
            <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="<MyTotal>">\
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<MyMerchantID>">\
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">\
            <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">\
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<MyReturnURL>">\
        </form>';
```

Indeed, the only information I get on the return page with a `var_dump($_REQUEST);` is

```
array(2) {
  ["tx"] => string(17) "<NumbersAndLettersInCaps>"
  ["CSCMATCH"] => string(1) "M"
}
```

Shouldn't I get more info such as payment status and others? And what is IPN and what is the difference with setting up a return URL?

Many thanks for any help!

**Edit**
Links in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295849/what-data-is-posted-back-to-the-paypal-return-url-and-how-do-i-send-my-own-da) are broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
    $payId = $_POST['tx'];

    $data = array(
        'USER' => urlencode('<MyLogin>'),
        'PWD' => urlencode('<MyPassword>'),
        'SIGNATURE' => urlencode('<MyApiSignature>'),
        'VERSION' => urlencode('62.0'),
        'METHOD' => urlencode('GetTransactionDetails'),
        'TRANSACTIONID' => urlencode($payId),
    );

    $url = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?'.http_build_query($data);
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    parse_str($result, $return);
```

`$return` which gives me the following:

```
array (size=32)
  'RECEIVERBUSINESS' => string '<EmailAdress>' (length=22)
  'RECEIVEREMAIL' => string '<EmailAdress>' (length=22)
  'RECEIVERID' => string '<RECEIVERID>' (length=13)
  'PAYERID' => string '<PAYERID>' (length=13)
  'PAYERSTATUS' => string 'verified' (length=8)
  'COUNTRYCODE' => string 'US' (length=2)
  'ADDRESSOWNER' => string 'PayPal' (length=6)
  'ADDRESSSTATUS' => string 'None' (length=4)
  'SALESTAX' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'SHIPAMOUNT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'SHIPHANDLEAMOUNT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2014-04-17T18:15:52Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string 'c5b81c633c4b4' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Success' (length=7) // Payment status
  'VERSION' => string '62.0' (length=4)
  'BUILD' => string '10277387' (length=8)
  'TRANSACTIONID' => string '<TRANSACTIONID>' (length=17)
  'RECEIPTID' => string '<RECEIPTID>' (length=19)
  'TRANSACTIONTYPE' => string 'integralEvolution' (length=17)
  'PAYMENTTYPE' => string 'instant' (length=7)
  'ORDERTIME' => string '2014-04-17T14:35:58Z' (length=20)
  'AMT' => string '<AMT>' (length=6)
  'FEEAMT' => string '<FEEAMT>' (length=4)
  'TAXAMT' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'CURRENCYCODE' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
  'PAYMENTSTATUS' => string 'Completed' (length=9)
  'PENDINGREASON' => string 'None' (length=4)
  'REASONCODE' => string 'None' (length=4)
  'PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY' => string 'Ineligible' (length=10)
  'L_QTY0' => string '1' (length=1)
  'L_TAXAMT0' => string '0.00' (length=4)
  'L_CURRENCYCODE0' => string 'EUR' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tx variable is the transaction ID. You need to use this variable to verify your payment status with a call to their API. The simplest way is to perform a [NVP](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/NVPAPIOverview/) call [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)

I suggest you to use the official [PHP SDK](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php) from Paypal they also have [an example](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/payments/GetPayment.php) for capturing a TransactionID details.

```
<?php
// # GetPaymentSample
// This sample code demonstrate how you can
// retrieve a list of all Payment resources
// you've created using the Payments API.
// Note various query parameters that you can
// use to filter, and paginate through the
// payments list.
// API used: GET /v1/payments/payments

require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap.php';
use PayPal\Api\Payment;

$paymentId = "PAY-0XL713371A312273YKE2GCNI";

// ### Retrieve payment
// Retrieve the payment object by calling the
// static `get` method
// on the Payment class by passing a valid
// Payment ID
// (See bootstrap.php for more on `ApiContext`)
try {
    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
    echo "Exception:" . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($ex->getData());
    exit(1);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lookup a payment</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Retrieving Payment ID: <?php echo $paymentId;?></div>
    <pre><?php var_dump($payment->toArray());?></pre>
    <a href='../index.html'>Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

IPN stands for Instant Payment Notification and is another way to get the results of a payments. This is a bit more complex implementation and I suggest you too look at it with more patience. [Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'll investigate on the way you gave me and get back to you :)

Comment: I see a lot of tutorial over the internet which recommend to use `$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);`, is it another way of doing it?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using `curl` instead of Paypal SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal will give you all the details regarding the Payment. You can view the returned data by -

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_REQUEST); exit;
```

The result will be `whole array` of details viz. Payment status, Bank Details, Order Details, etc and you can use this data for viewing purpose or can store them in your database.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! I edited my post as per your requirment but I get the same info as I posted earlier with a `print_r($_REQUEST);`